# Populating fields from 1 object into another through (for ... in ...) loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, for-in-loop

The issue I'm having is as follows: I'm attempting to populate a Javascript object (called Table) with content from another object (called Messages)

I'm trying to do this by matching 2 keys in the Table object with 2 keys from the Messages object. The keys I'm trying to match can be described as 'row' and 'cell'.

If the message 'row' and 'cell' match, I push the message into the cell.

**Information**
 - Rows are unique keys at the top level of the object and are called 'labs'.
 - Cells are unique keys in Rows, but a Cell key might have a duplicate in another row. They are called 'steps'.

My thoughts were that to uniquely identify a cell, it would be possible to compare the Row + Cell key of the Table cell I want to populate with the Row + Cell key of the message. If they match, populate the Table cell.

**The object I'm trying to populate looks as following (before population):**

```
{
    "570f5233c8640c8819dae6a2": {
        "570f5215c8640c8819dae6a0": {
            "_id": "570f5215c8640c8819dae6a0",
            "time": 2,
            "type": "Type 1",
            "order": 0,
            "messages": []
        },
        "570f927196fa91ab0a1d8793": {
            "_id": "570f927196fa91ab0a1d8793",
            "time": 0,
            "type": "Type 2",
            "order": 1,
            "messages": []
        }
    },
    "570f52caecbdcb2c1a7031f1": {
        "570f5215c8640c8819dae6a0": {
            "_id": "570f5215c8640c8819dae6a0",
            "time": 2,
            "type": "Type 1",
            "order": 0,
            "messages": []
        },
        "570f927196fa91ab0a1d8793": {
            "_id": "570f927196fa91ab0a1d8793",
            "time": 0,
            "type": "Type 2",
            "order": 1,
            "messages": []
        }
    }
}
```

**The code I'm using to populate the object above as follows (I'm populating the messages field):**

```
for (let msgKey in messages) {
    if (messages.hasOwnProperty(msgKey)) {

        for (let tableRowKey in table) {
            if (table.hasOwnProperty(tableRowKey)) {

                for (let cellRowKey in table[tableRowKey]) {
                    if (table[tableRowKey].hasOwnProperty(cellRowKey)) {

                        let msgRow = messages[msgKey].lab.toString();
                        let msgStep = messages[msgKey].step.toString();

                        if (tableRowKey === msgRow && cellRowKey === msgStep) {
                            table[tableRowKey][cellRowKey].messages.push(messages[msgKey]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The output from the code looks as follows (after population):**

```
{
    "570f5233c8640c8819dae6a2": {
        "570f5215c8640c8819dae6a0": {
            "_id": "570f5215c8640c8819dae6a0",
            "time": 2,
            "type": "Type 1",
            "order": 0,
            "messages": [
            {
                "step": "570f5215c8640c8819dae6a0",
                "time": 2,
                "timeActual": 0.00010335648148148148,
                "timeDifference": null,
                "isComplete": true,
                "lab": "570f5233c8640c8819dae6a2"
            }
            ]
        },
        "570f927196fa91ab0a1d8793": {
            "_id": "570f927196fa91ab0a1d8793",
            "time": 0,
            "type": "Type 2",
            "order": 1,
            "messages": [
            {
                "step": "570f927196fa91ab0a1d8793",
                "time": 0,
                "timeActual": 0.00007015046296296297,
                "timeDifference": null,
                "isComplete": true,
                "lab": "570f52caecbdcb2c1a7031f1"
            }
            ]
        }
    },
    "570f52caecbdcb2c1a7031f1": {
        "570f5215c8640c8819dae6a0": {
            "_id": "570f5215c8640c8819dae6a0",
            "time": 2,
            "type": "Type 1",
            "order": 0,
            "messages": [
            {
                "step": "570f5215c8640c8819dae6a0",
                "time": 2,
                "timeActual": 0.00010335648148148148,
                "timeDifference": null,
                "isComplete": true,
                "lab": "570f5233c8640c8819dae6a2"
            }
            ]
        },
        "570f927196fa91ab0a1d8793": {
            "_id": "570f927196fa91ab0a1d8793",
            "time": 0,
            "type": "Type 2",
            "order": 1,
            "messages": [
            {
                "step": "570f927196fa91ab0a1d8793",
                "time": 0,
                "timeActual": 0.00007015046296296297,
                "timeDifference": null,
                "isComplete": true,
                "lab": "570f52caecbdcb2c1a7031f1"
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If it was matching correctly, the message would be populated in an object when the message "lab" key and the message "step" key matched the parent keys. So a correct object would look as follows:

```
    "570f5233c8640c8819dae6a2": {
        "570f5215c8640c8819dae6a0": {
            "_id": "570f5215c8640c8819dae6a0",
            "time": 2,
            "type": "Type 1",
            "order": 0,
            "messages": [
            {
                "step": "570f5215c8640c8819dae6a0",
                "time": 2,
                "timeActual": 0.00010335648148148148,
                "timeDifference": null,
                "isComplete": true,
                "lab": "570f5233c8640c8819dae6a2"
            }
            ]
        }
```

However, the code is in fact populating messages in fields where the parent keys do not match, as you can see from the after population code included above.

What exactly is wrong here, to me the code looks correct, am I missing something about matching Javascript keys?

Comment: Where is recursion in this question? There isn't even one function in your code.

Comment: Good point. Edited question to reflect this.